# How to add a single react to a non react project in ASP.NET Core 3 MVC?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I am making a multiplayer card game as a university project and I already wrote the code for lobbies and sockets with signalR and every other page is complete with basic html/css. One of my groupmates suggested using React.js for the actual game page(where the cards will be moved and etc)

How to add that one react-app page to your entire mvc web project? (since it has so many files and folders  and needs a compiler)

Comment: I removed off-topic part of the post (asking for opinions on which framework is "better" in general or for you personally is off-topic as opinion based, asking 2 separate questions in the post makes post too broad to have on concrete answer)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i did not ask if its better i asked if there is a point in using it